# iPhone 7 won't activate and can't access Apple Support or iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, sim

My new iPhone 7 recently had an error that said it lost cellular connectivity and required an update. I'm traveling and don't have access to iTunes (on work computer and I cannot install software). I spoke to my cellular provider (Ting) and they couldn't identify an issue and recommended I do a factory reset. After resetting, the phone now says it cannot connect to the activation network (says it's not available), only has Wi-Fi connectivity, and occasionally has an error that says it can't be activated because the activation data is not available.

I cannot access Apple Support because it requires Two-factor authentication, and since my iPhone won't work, I cannot get the validation code (that is extremely frustrating), and this means I can't post on the Apple Support site. Also, since my iPhone won't work, I can't call Apple Support.

Other things I've tried (from this site and Apple support forum) included removing the SIM card and powering off and on. I've tried activating it for two days on different Wi-Fi networks, tried connecting to another computer with iTunes, but ran into the Two-factor catch-22. I went to the Apple Support process of recovering my Apple ID, and they say that will take several days and hasn't resulted in anything useful at this point.

Is there anything else I can try to activate my iPhone? Would could possible cause this problem - software or hardware (e.g. SIM card)? Am I just totally out of luck? If I didn't happen to have my work computer I could just be stranded.

UPDATE: I returned home and was finally able to contact Apple support. There is a service issue with my iPhone model (A1660), and there is a [repair program from Apple](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone-7-no-service/) to fix the hardware issue. I'm going to the store today and will update with results.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It appears that your SIM card is not able to active itself as it is not in its home network and roaming. And if that's the case, Wi-Fi connectivity won't help to active your SIM card. Also, let us know how did you manage to get the Two-factor authentication code after factory resetting the iPhone? or did you skip past setting up an Apple ID on the iPhone?

Comment: I didn't know about that -- good point. Strangely this happened again a few days ago and magically corrected itself overnight.